# Inconveniente al iterar un array en Swift

Tags: swift

estoy aprendiendo sobre swift y me encuentro con el siguiente inconveniente.

Tengo un json al que llega informacion de gps desde una API, y necesito marcar el inicio y el fin del recorrido con un icono distinto al resto de los puntos.

Escribi el siguiente codigo:

```
if json.first != nil {
self.icon = "house"
}
if json.last != nil {
self.icon = "end"
}
```

Mi problema surge en que se le otorgan a todos los elementos del json el icono "end". Cuando yo unicamente quiero que lo tenga el ultimo elemento y el primero tenga el icono "start"
Como puedo trabajar unicamente con el primer y el ultimo item del array, sin afectar a todos los elementos del array?

Comment: Qué te devuelve `json.first`? Así como está el código, si se cumplen las dos condiciones el valor de `self.icon` siempre va a ser "end".

Comment: me devolvia house, pero luego entraba en json.last y me devolvia end. Lo solucione de creando un nuevo array con el primero y el ultimo punto.

Comment: Puedes agregar la solución como respuesta, así ayudas a quien tenga el mismo inconveniente.